# Question on continuous function between squares

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, continuity, connectedness, geometric-topology

Let $Q\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be the square determined by the points $(0,0)$, $(4,0)$, $(4,4)$, $(0,4)$ and let $f:Q\rightarrow Q$ be any continuous function which fixes the four points $(0,0)$, $(4,0)$, $(4,4)$, $(0,4)$.

Denote by $d\subset Q$ the diagonal between $(0,0)$ and $(4,4)$ and by $f(d)$ its image by $f$: it is clear that $f(d)$ is a continuos path in $Q$ between $(0,0)$ and $(4,4)$. The path $f(d)$ splits $Q$ in many parts, denote by $Q'_0$ the one containing $f(4,0)$.

**Question**: is it true that $f(2,1)$ must be contained in $Q'_0$?

My guess would be "yes", I'll explain my reasoning.

The function $f:Q\setminus d\rightarrow Q\setminus f(d)$ is still continuous and thus must send connected sets to connected sets. Since $f$ fixes $(4,0)$ then the lower triangle must be sent entirely in $Q_0'$.

Is it right?

Comment: @RobArthan Are you sure that my proof is correct? User Will Jagy claims that he has found a counter-example

Comment: I was wrong about this. The statement isn't true without some additional assumption (e.g., that $f$ is one-to-one). I will write up an answer with a counter-example.

Answer (score 0):

well, no. The square can be folded... For some point $ 0 < x+y \leq 4,$ define
$$ T = x+y $$ and then
$$ \lambda = \frac{y}{T} = \frac{y}{x+y}. $$
The fraction $\lambda = 0$ refers to the point $(T,0). $ The fraction $\lambda = 1$ refers to the point $(0,T). $ Then let
$$  f(x,y) = (T,0) + \left( 16 \lambda^3 - 24 \lambda^2 + 9 \lambda \right) (-T,T).  $$
With some effort, this can be written out as two rational functions of $x,y.$

I have not written it down yet, the behavior for $4 < x+y < 8$ is a mirror image of what I said above.
FRIDAY: For some point $ 4 \leq x+y \leq 8,$ define
$$ T = x+y $$ but then
$$ \lambda = \frac{y+4-T}{8-T}. $$
The fraction $\lambda = 0$ refers to the point $(4,T-4). $ The fraction $\lambda = 1$ refers to the point $(T-4,4). $ Then let
$$  f(x,y) = (4,T-4) + \left( 16 \lambda^3 - 24 \lambda^2 + 9 \lambda \right) (T-8, 8-T).  $$

For any $x = y$ we get $\lambda = 1/2$ and $f(T/2,T/2) = (T/2,T/2).$

For your $(2,1)$ we get $T=3,$ then $\lambda = 1/3,$ then 
$$  f(2,1) = (3,0) + \left( \frac{25}{27} \right) (-3,3)=\left( \frac{2}{9}, \frac{25}{9} \right) .  $$

[image]

Comment: I don't know, this seems correct... But my reasoning too seems correct.. are you sure your function is continuous on the whole square? Can you find an error in my proof?

Comment: I found the error in your answer: it results $f(4,2)=(4/9,50/9)$ which is not in $Q$. So the function you presented is not a function from $Q$ to $Q$.

Comment: @user, as I said, I had not written the $T,\lambda$ stuff for $4 \leq x+y \leq 8.$

Comment: With the expressions for $x+y > 4,$ your point $(4,2)$ has $T=6$ but $\lambda = 0,$ and is mapped to itself.

Comment: so, where is the error in my proof?

Comment: @user493456   I didn't quite get what you wrote. A connected set is sent to a connected set by a continuous map, that is fine. However, if you have two connected components, there is nothing to prevent their images from overlapping; that is all I did. Put another way, there is no reason the inverse image of a connected set needs to be connected.

Comment: of course the images of two connected components can overlap. but they must be both contained in the same connected component of the codomain. since $(2,1)$ is in the same connected component (in the domain) of $(4,0)$, it results that $f(2,1)$ must be in the same connected component of $f(4,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

Your argument holds if $f$ is one-to-one, but if $f(Q \setminus d) \cap (Q \setminus f(d)) \neq \emptyset $, the statement is not true in general. Your proposed proof assumes that $f$ restricts to a function of $Q \setminus d $ to $Q \setminus f(d)$, but if that is not true, we can find a counter-example.

For example, we can design a continuous $f$ from $Q = [0, 4] \times [0, 4]$ to itself with the following properties, where $A = (0, 0)$, $B = (0, 4)$, $C = (4, 4)$ and $D = (0, 4)$ are the vertices of the square $Q$ and where $Z = (3, 0)$ (a point lying on the lower horizontal edge $AB$ to the east of the point $X = (2, 1)$ that we are trying to isolate from $B$ in $f(Q)$):

1. $f$ maps the rectangle $[0, 3] \times [0, 4]$ to the triangle $\triangle AZD$.
2. $f$ maps the rectangle $[3, 4] \times [0, 4]$ to the triangle $\triangle ZBC$.
3. $f$ fixes $A, B, C, D$ and $Z$.

So the image of such an $f$ is contained in the union of the two triangles $\triangle AZD$ and $\triangle ZBC$. Given such an $f$, the image $f(d)$ of the diagonal $d$ contains the point $Z$ so removing $f(d)$ will separate $f(B) = B = (4, 0)$ from $f(X) = f((2, 1)) \in \triangle AZD$.

To construct an example of such an $f$, we can scale each vertical interval $\{x\} \times [0, 4]$ in $Q$ to map it onto the vertical interval through $\triangle AZD$ or $\triangle ZBC$ that it meets:

$$
f((x, y)) = \left\{%
\begin{array}{l@{\quad}l}
(x, \frac{3-x}{3}y) & \mbox{if $x \in [0, 3]$} \\
(x, (x - 3)y) & \mbox{if $x \in [3, 4]$}
\end{array}\right.
$$